# up-arrow key to search for 2 words given with zsh shell

Tags: shell, zsh

With zsh/oh-my-zsh/iterm2, excellent way to navigate through the terminal command history.

If I issued a command say `knife cookbook upload application` few days before and to get the command, I can do `k` or `kni` or `knif` and press the up-arrow key, it'll iterate through the commands history that starts with `knife` word.

But if the similar commands have ran that starts out with `knife`, I'll have to iterate over the commands using up-arrow key.

But if I wanted to search through more than one word, say to get commands with both `knife node`, zsh doesn't support this and starts to show the commands that starts with just `knife`.

So, is there any way to get the commands that starts with two words? so that I just type two words and pressing up-arrow key to show only those commands that starts with two words typed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to @Shep answer I would suggest changing `<C-r>` behavior from searching just only plain strings to searching glob patterns:

```
bindkey "\C-r" history-incremental-pattern-search-backward
```

. In this case you will achieve desired result by searching for `knife*node`. By the way, if you did `knife node<Up>`, zsh should search for commands that start with `knife node`, not just with `knife`. But it won’t search for commands that contain both `knife` and `node` separated by other words, as well as it won’t search for commands that contain `knife node` not at the start of the line (talking about `history-beginning-search-backward` widget).

Comment: exactly looking for as you've said. when I type `knife node<Up>` I want just those commands that starts with `knife node`. But though I type `knife node<up>`, it still shows all the commands that starts with `knife`.

Comment: @Millisami You should be sure that `<Up>` is binded to `history-beginning-search-backward` widget because I never saw different behavior. But I am using zsh from version 4.3.10 or 4.3.9 AFAIR, if you have an older one then maybe something changed. I see in `man zshzle` there is a `history-search-backward` widget mapped by default to `<Esc>N` and `<Esc>n`, it has the same behavior you describe. Try to search your zshrc for line containing this widget name and replace it with `history-beginning-search-backward` (and do the similar action for `history-search-forward` to make it consistent).

Comment: By the way, I am not saying that this widget is binded by default. But I do not see *any* widget binded to `<Up>` key by default, so it must be a mapping. AFAIK Mac OS (iterm2=Mac OS X, am I right?) has some defaults for zsh somewhere in /etc (on Gentoo I have them in `/etc/zsh/zprofile`, but there are no binds and no defaults not required for zsh to work properly), or it may be binded by oh-my-zsh files, you may also search these locations, but it is better to just add a bind to your zshrc.

Comment: Thanks, it was the issue of the key binding. I added this bindings and it works: `bindkey "^[[A" history-beginning-search-backward` and `bindkey "^[[B" history-beginning-search-forward`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not exactly what you're looking for, but typing C-r will open a backward command search, which will search for any string you entered, starting with the most recent. To get the second most recent, press control-r again (and so on).

Also see a [related thread](https://superuser.com/questions/197813/cycle-through-matches-in-zsh-history-incremental-pattern-search-backward) on superuser.

Comment: @Shef, well I know that reverse search. But its not exactly I am looking for. Thanks.